# Pandas - After I created dummy columns how do I given a new vector get the dummy representation?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn, dummy-variable

Some of my columns contain textual categoric values like
"`did_do_something`" with the possible values of "`true`" or "`false`" or another column might be "`browser_type`" with possible values of "`chrome`", "`safari`" but I also have other columns containing numeric category "enumeration" such as "`version_type`" which could have a value like `"1" ,"2" ,"3" ,"4"` and then there are just plain numeric columns like "`age`" which just get a numeric value and should stay unaltered.

I checked the `pandas` documentation here https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html

Specifically this flag:

> columns : list-like, default None
>
> Column names in the DataFrame to be encoded. If columns is None then
>   all the columns with object or category dtype will be converted.

My dummy processing looks like this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

data_csv_file = 'data/data.csv'

data = pd.read_table(data_csv_file,delimiter = ",").dropna()

# this is the column containing the label for the row
label_column = 'converted_pixel'

# these columns SHOULD NOT be encoded since they are read numeric values
numeric_columns = ['campaign_frequency','user_age_days']

# all the other columns which are not label or numeric should be dummy encoded
dummy_columns = [a for a in data.columns if a != label_column and a not in numeric_columns]

# create the new processed data frame with the dummy columns
processed_dummy_data = pd.get_dummies(data,columns = dummy_columns)
```

The processed data frame results in around 1000 columns from the original 21 columns.

My question is given a vector from the original dataframe, how can I get it's dummy encoding from the resulting dummy ?

Since the dummy data frame is so large, it is unreasonable to do this on my own.

I am looking for an API like

```
dummy_encoded_vector = get_dummy_encoding(vector_from_original_dataframe_encoding, processed_dummy_data)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can using `str.contains`

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':list('abcde'),'B':list('abcde')})

s=pd.get_dummies(df)

yourcol='A'

s.loc[:,s.columns.str.contains(yourcol+'_')]

Out[117]: 
   A_a  A_b  A_c  A_d  A_e
0    1    0    0    0    0
1    0    1    0    0    0
2    0    0    1    0    0
3    0    0    0    1    0
4    0    0    0    0    1
```